# How to align icons and buttons inside a list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Collapsible List]

I have a collapsible list, as shown.
I am trying to align all of the right arrow icons to the end, so they are all aligned in the same y-axis.

I would like to achieve this using flexbox, or another clean solution that doesn't involve margin-left: etc.

I have tried adding align and justify properties to the .fa-caret-right class, without success.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="sec3">
      <ul class="sec2drop">
        <li>
          <button class="collapsible">
            Prepare for a language exam
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible2">
            Hungarian for kids <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible3">
            Take on a challenge <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible4">
            Translation services <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.sec2drop li {
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(161, 159, 159);
  line-height: 50px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another tag for the text in the button. So you can control the text and icon separately.
You can use flex-grow for the text can grow and the icon will be not growing.

```css
.sec2drop li {
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(161, 159, 159);
  line-height: 50px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  width:100%;

}

.collapsible .text {
  text-align: left;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.collapsible i {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="sec3">
  <ul class="sec2drop">
    <li>
      <button class="collapsible">
        <span class="text"> Prepare for a language exam</span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right">></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible2">
        <span class="text"> Hungarian for kids </span><i class="fa fa-caret-right">></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible3">
        <span class="text"> Take on a challenge </span><i class="fa fa-caret-right">></i>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="collapsible" id="collapsible4">
        <span class="text"> Translation services </span><i class="fa fa-caret-right">></i>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div
```